# Fallthrough with coldfusion cfswitch tag?

Tags: coldfusion, switch-statement, coldfusion-11

Can anyone point me to an idiom for intentional switch fallthrough using cfswitch?

My desire is for something similar the following to output "αβ"; currently it does the 'sane' thing and implicitly breaks:

```
<cfswitch expression="α">
    <cfcase value="α">
        <cfoutput>α</cfoutput>
        <!--- explicit fallthrough to next case here? --->
    </cfcase>
    <cfcase value="β">
        <cfoutput>β</cfoutput>
        <!--- explicit break here? --->
    </cfcase>
    <cfdefaultcase>
        <cfoutput>γ</cfoutput>
    </cfdefaultcase>
</cfswitch>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, it can't be done with the tag based version. This line from the documentation seems to confirm [CFCASE](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-c/cfcase.html) always performs a break:

> "... **You do not have to explicitly break out of the cfcase tag**.."

However, the cfscript version doesn't. It behaves more like java's [switch/case](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html). After matching `α`, it'll fall through to all subsequent cases, unless explicitly told to `break`.

```
<cfscript>
switch("α") {
    case "α":
         WriteOutput("α");
    case "β":
         WriteOutput("β");
         break; // explicit break
    default: 
         WriteOutput("γ");
}
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Ageax yes this is unfortunately true. I also found CF allows delimited lists as cases (e.g., `case "α,β"`), which provides some relief to similar problems—but not this problem (assuming one cannot use cfscript due to project constraints).

Comment: What's the reason for the restriction? If this functionality is *really* needed, lack of support seems like a good reason for making an exception...

Answer (score 0):

If the input value is `α` how is it possible that the check for `β` would even succeed and thus output `αβ`?

Comment: Some languages, like java, use [a fall-through approach](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html). "All statements after the matching case label are executed in sequence, regardless of the expression of subsequent case labels, until a break statement is encountered.". So with a well placed `break`, the result could be "αβ".